# Get checkBox unchecked state

Tags: c#, if-statement, checkbox, user-controls

I need to implement a check box to switch between two methods enabling/disabling some control. I am using the following code, I tried also in other ways but no luck.

```
  private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (checkBox1.Checked)//this is working
                {
                    trackBar2.Enabled = false;
                    button3.PerformClick();
                    textBox8.Enabled = true;
                }

            else// this is supposed to work if checkbox is unchecked but doesn't work
            {
                trackBar2.Enabled = true;
                textBox8.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

The result I get is always the same. If I check the checkbox the first condition is meet and it is fine. If I uncheck the text box, nothing happen and does not go back to the first condition either.
How can I detect the checked/unchecked condition?

Comment: I prefer the Click event for this type of handling.

Comment: Does your button3.PerformClick() change the state of the checkbox at all?
Do you ever manual remove or add the events for the check box?
This seems like it should work as is, odd that it doesn't

Comment: Your original code works for me...

Comment: @Idle_Mind, thats funny. It doesn't for me! However thanks you for testing. I sorted out the problem as per Vink answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add `if(checkBox1.Checked == false)` to the else :

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (checkBox1.Checked)//this is working
        {
                trackBar2.Enabled = false;
                button3.PerformClick();
                textBox8.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if(checkBox1.Checked == false)
        {
            trackBar2.Enabled = true;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I was quite sure I tried it but obviously I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

You could also write that as:

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trackBar2.Enabled = !checkBox1.Checked;
        textBox8.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            button3.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```